# Starting multiple thread at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have been trying to write some java application.
What this application wants to run is processing a text file.

However, that input text file is large, (over 200mb)
I tried to split 200mb as four split files (50mb each)

Then, using four threads, tries to process each of split simultaneously.

So, I make a class which implements runnable, and it has a text process module.
Then, I make 4 obj of that (named worker1 ~ worker4) runnnable class then call:

```
worker1.run();
worker2.run();
worker3.run();
worker4.run();
```

However, these threads are not running simultaneously, but running linearly.
This means, after worker 1 thread is finished, then worker2 thread is running.

So, each of them takes just 0.5 sec, but with this linear running, It tooks 2 secs each. (0.5s for worker1 + 0.5s for worker2 + 0.5s for worker3 + 0.5s for worker4)
If I can run 4 threads at the same time, I expected that this application takes just about 0.5 sec or less than 1 sec which is faster than 2 secs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Keep in mind that in this case, quite likely, processing the file in multiple threads will perform worse, not better.

Comment: 200MB isn't a huge file. You can read it in a second or two. What makes you think multiple threads will be faster? Do you have a multithreaded disk?

Comment: 200 mb isn't huge, actually. However, in my case, it tooks nearly 20 seconds to process. However, i split 4 workers and then process it. This took 4.33 seconds to process. Multiple but process different part of input is much fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start a thread. So:

```
new Thread(worker1).start();
new Thread(worker2).start();
new Thread(worker3).start();
new Thread(worker4).start();
```

Comment: Yes by this all threads will start working simultaneously. Invoking run() method will not start a thread rather it will be treated as a method of that class. So to start a thread always call start() on thread.

Answer (score 1):

Runnable object is not Thread, you need use Thread to run the Runnable Object, like this:

```
new Thread(worker1).start();
```

but i think you may face other problems, so please read the java document.

Answer (score 1):

Reading files on one disk usually does not benefit from multithreading.

Try to improve the way you read and process the file. Use a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) if you do not already use a buffer.

If you do a lot of processing from what is read, then consider multithreading the processing while keeping one thread dedicating to reading.

To run concurrent tasks, you should use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that you instanciate thanks to [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). Take some time to read the javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

```
worker1.run();
```

calls your run method directly. To start a thread (which calls your run method in the new thread), use:

```
worker1.start();
```

(similar for worker2/3/4)

Edit: I thought the workers were Threads, not Runnables. mvieghofer's answer is correct.